# Can output current be higher than what the input source can provide

Tags: current, mosfet, switches

One basic question.Am controlling a group of LEDs (connected in series and parallel) through a MOSFET switch.The input voltage is provided by a battery @ 5V,2A rating.
The total current consumption of LEDs is about 4A,higher than what the input can provide.
Can output current be higher than the input ? Please provide me insight on this.

Answer (score 4):

The rating of the battery is probably Ampere-hours, not Amperes.

The Ampere-hour rating of a battery relates to the amount of energy stored in the battery, not to the current it can deliver.  A 2 Ah battery could theoretically deliver 2 Amps for 1 hour, or 1 Amp for 2 hours, etc. If you draw 4 Amps from a 2 Ah battery, it will be fully discharged in less than 30 minutes (If you discharge a battery at a high rate, you will get fewer Ah from it than the rating indicates)

After further thought, I noticed that you said the battery was 5 volts - as there is no battery chemistry that will directly produce 5 volts, I suspect you have a "power pack" consisting of a battery and a DC/DC converter, designed to charge cell phones, rather than a plain battery.

In that case, the 2 Amp rating would be the designed output rating of the DC/DC converter, and attempting to draw more than 2 Amps from the power pack may damage the DC/DC converter.

Comment: Usually the manufacturers rate the maximum current of their batteries as a multiple of the capacity, say 1C or 2C. Lithium tech have a built in protection. Just saying the theory stops here, there is a limit to how much current a battery can provide. In fact it depends on the age of the battery as well - maybe the 1C etc. still stands but considering the real capacity of the battery (which drops over time)? I guess there is no limit other than a non linear drop in effective capacity for other techs.

Answer (score 1):

Voltage and current can almost always be interchanged as long as the total power remains the same. Using a buck/boost regulator, one can sacrifice one for the other at the cost of a little power loss.